# could not convert string to float: '2,550,000,000'

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to fit a module to my dataframe but im getting `could not convert string to float: '2,550,000,000'` error. please take a look at my codes below:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.compose import make_column_transformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler, OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
houseprice = pd.read_csv('houseprice.csv')
houseprice = houseprice.drop("Price", axis=1)
print(houseprice)
```

the outcome of the `Print(houseprice)` is this: [image]

here is the rest of my code that i'm getting the error in this part

```
# creating X and y (test set and train set)
ct = make_column_transformer(
    (MinMaxScaler(), ["Area", "Room"]),
    (OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown="ignore"), ["Parking", "Warehouse", "Elevator", "Address"])
)

X = houseprice.drop("Price(USD)", axis=1)
y = houseprice["Price(USD)"]
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

ct.fit(X_train)
```

and here is a picture of my error (im trying to compile it in google colab but im getting this error in vscode too):
[image]

I would appreciate if someone can help me

Comment: what dataset are you using? without the data it is hard to reproduce this question.

Comment: @RoseGod its a CSV file. i shared a picture of it in my question section above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the thousands separator when you read the file like this:

```
houseprice = pd.read_csv('houseprice.csv', thousands=',')
```